# Batch no asigna bien el %%i a la variable

Tags: batch, .bat

me estoy volviendo un poco loco porque creo que lo tengo bien, y seguro que un detalle que no veo.

**Objetivo**: guardar en un fichero csv 4 campos, nombreComponente, Versión, archivo, versionArhivo.

```
Ejemplo:
componente1, 1.28.4, 2023.11.29, 3.387.4     
componente2, 1.28.0, 2023.11.29, 3.387.4     
componente3, 1.12.1, 2023.11.29, 3.387.4
```

**Que tengo**: un directorio con varios archivos.txt. Sus nombres están dentro de un txt. Por ejemplo:

```
Ficheros.txt 
2023.11.08-3.381.2.txt
2023.11.16-3.382.1.txt
2023.11.29-3.387.4.txt
```

En cada archivo txt tengo un componente y su versión. Ejemplo:

```
"componente1": "1.30.3",   
"componente2": "1.29.4",   
"componente3": "1.13.0",   
"componente4": "1.9.2",
```

Cada archivo tiene los mismos componentes con versión diferente.

**Que estoy haciendo**

Por cada fichero.txt recorro todo su contenido y separa componente y versión y guardo un registro con componente, versión, fichero, fecha.

Este es el código:

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (ficheros.txt) do (
    echo El fichero es %%i
    
    :: Asigno el valor a la variable nombreFichero
    set nombreFichero=%%i   
    echo Nombre Fichero es %nombreFichero%
    
    :: Elimino .txt
    set nombreFichero=%nombreFichero:.txt=%
    echo El nombre ahora tiene %nombreFichero%
    
    :: Obtengo versión del nombre
    set version=%nombreFichero:*-=%
    echo Version es %version%

    :: Obtengo nombreFichero del nombre (pendiente de hacer)
    
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in (%%i) do (
        ::echo El componente es %%a y la version es %%b
        echo %%a,%%b,%nombreFichero%,%version% >> componentes.txt
    )   
    
)
```

Pero, esto es lo que devuelve los echo:

```
El fichero es 2023.11.08-3.381.2.txt
Nombre Fichero es 2023.11.29-3.387.4
El nombre ahora tiene 2023.11.29-3.387.4
Version es 3.387.4
El componente es "componente1" y la version es  "1.28.4",
El componente es "componente2" y la version es  "1.6.0",
El fichero es 2023.11.16-3.382.1.txt
Nombre Fichero es 2023.11.29-3.387.4
El nombre ahora tiene 2023.11.29-3.387.4
Version es 3.387.4
El componente es "componente1" y la version es  "1.28.3",
El componente es "componente2" y la version es  "1.5.29",
El fichero es 2023.11.29-3.387.4.txt
Nombre Fichero es 2023.11.29-3.387.4
El nombre ahora tiene 2023.11.29-3.387.4
Version es 3.387.4
El componente es "componente1" y la version es  "1.28.2",
El componente es "componente2" y la version es  "1.4.0",
```

Y esto es lo que contiene el fichero componentes.txt

```
"componente1", "1.28.4",   ,2023.11.29-3.387.4      ,3.387.4 
"componente2", "1.28.0",   ,2023.11.29-3.387.4      ,3.387.4 
"componente3", "1.12.1",   ,2023.11.29-3.387.4      ,3.387.4
```

Se me que me falta de formatear el nombre del fichero para sacar el nombre, pero antes quería comprobar que estoy en buen camino.

El error que veo es que el valor de nombreFichero siempre es el mismo: 2023.11.29-3.387.4 (Que es el nombre del último fichero) en lugar de actualizarse con %%i. Y que por lo tanto %version% siempre es el mismo valor. Lo correcto debería ser:

```
2023.11.08-3.381.2
2023.11.16-3.382.1
2023.11.29-3.387.4

Y para versión:
3.381.2
3.382.1
3.387.4

Con resultado en el fichero componentes.txt
componente1, 1.28.5, 2023.11.08 ,3.387.2 
componente2, 1.28.1, 2023.11.08 ,3.387.2 
componente3, 1.12.2, 2023.11.08 ,3.387.2
componente1, 1.28.4, 2023.11.16 ,3.387.1 
componente2, 1.28.0, 2023.11.16 ,3.387.1 
componente3, 1.12.1, 2023.11.16 ,3.387.1
componente1, 1.28.8, 2023.11.29 ,3.387.4 
componente2, 1.28.4, 2023.11.29 ,3.387.4 
componente3, 1.12.12, 2023.11.29 ,3.387.4
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal???